# How to Upload and Retrieve image in latest firebase storage after update

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage, image-uploading

I am trying to upload and retrieve the image and follow all the results available at Stack and tutorials but none of example help me.

how to upload an image on button click in latest firebase storage

I am following this tutorial
https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/firebase-storage-example/

```
StorageReference reference= storageReference.child(System.currentTimeMillis()+ "."+getFileExtension(filePath));
            mUploadTask= reference.putFile(filePath);
            Task<Uri> urlTask = mUploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
                @Override
                public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        throw task.getException();
                    }

                    // Continue with the task to get the download URL
                    return storageReference.getDownloadUrl();
                }
            }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
                    } else {
                        // Handle failures
                        // ...
                    }
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it right to upload the image, after you return the `storageReference.getDownloadUrl()`, just set that value into your firebase database.

```
StorageReference reference= storageReference.child(System.currentTimeMillis()+ "."+getFileExtension(filePath));
            mUploadTask= reference.putFile(filePath);
            Task<Uri> urlTask = mUploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
                @Override
                public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        throw task.getException();
                    }

                    // Continue with the task to get the download URL
                    return storageReference.getDownloadUrl();
                }
            }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
                        mDatabaseRef.child("images").child("imageUrl").setValue(downloadUri.toString());
                    } else {
                        // Handle failures
                        // ...
                    }
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
```

You will need to request that image url String from firebase and after that, to show the image in any ImageView use [Picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/) or [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to load it.